# Bigquery Python API - Write dataframe order by column

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to write a `pandas.Dataframe` to Bigquery using the Python API, sorting records by a column:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("date", "DATE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("col1", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("col2", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("col3", "STRING")
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE"
)

job_update = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, output_table, job_config=job_config
)
```

The process correctly creates the table with the correct values, but the rows are not ordered by `date`. Is there a parameter / method to define the order in the `job_config`?

Comment: As with most relational databases, data in BigQuery should never be considered sorted. If you need it sorted you have to specify that in the query that you use to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments to the question there is no parameter / method to define the order for any specific column in the [job_config](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html).

Similarly with most relational databases, data in BigQuery should never be considered sorted. If you need it sorted you have to specify that in the query that you use to retrieve the data by using the [ORDER BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#order_by_clause) clause.