# BigQuery chaning order of columns while WRITE_TRUNCATE

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I create a BigQuery table with a few columns from Terraform.

```
column1, column2, column3, column4
```

In a Python script I write a Pandas Dataframe to this BigQuery table. But the dataframe has the columns in a different order.

df.head()

```
column4, column1, column2, column3.
```

My python script to write.

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset("dataset")

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'

load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        pandas_df, dataset_ref.table("table"),
        job_config=job_config)
```

After the script is run, I could see that the order of the columns in the BigQuery table is changed to `column4, column1, column2, column3`.

So next time when I try to run Terraform apply it sees it as a change and deletes and recreates the table again and I'm loosing all the contents of the table.

Is there any way to write the dataframe without forcefully changing the order of the original schema?

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68193174/) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew I don't need the rows to be sorted. i need the columns to have the same order as defined in terraform and shouldn't change.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design:

> WRITE_TRUNCATE: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the data, removes the constraints, and uses the schema from the query result.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job

If you need the table to conformed to a specified schema, you need to re-order the Data Frame column.